# How to get ImageView image size (Android)

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

i am working on an image gallery app in which i am loading images from internet and i am saving images to Sd Card on button click.

now what i want is i want to get the size of the image that is loaded in ImageView. i want to get image size in KB / Bytes.

i want to use image size to prevent duplicate save and replacing image.

this is my code that i am using to save image: 
same resolution images get replaced

```
    int intHeight = fullImageView.getHeight();
        int intWidth = fullImageView.getWidth();


        String dirname2 = "/Wallpapers/";

        File myDir2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath() + dirname2);

        myDir2.mkdirs();

        String fname2 = "image" + intHeight + intWidth +".jpeg";
        File file2 = new File(myDir2, fname2);

        if (file2.exists())
            file2.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file2);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(_context, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

**Please Note: i am asking about image size in KB or Bytes**

Comment: A gallery app that uses ImageView? That can contain only one picture. You will use a GridView or something like that i think. How come the image is in an ImageView?

Comment: Now you are just always that image. And it always has the same name. (image.jpeg). You couls start adapting your code in such a way that you determine the filelength first and your pseudo code to determine new file size and the determine if you want to delete and or save.

Comment: But your idea of doing it with filesize is only doable if you save it under a different name first and then compare the two file sizes. But then still it is not a good way of doing that what you want.

Comment: GridView + Full Screen ImageView. selected image from GridView send to Full Screen ImageView

Comment: And what is sent from gridview to full imageview? A bitmap? Or a filepath?

Comment: sending Bitmap gridview to full imageview

Comment: How can you hold a number of full size images in a GridView? No memory problems? What technic.code do you use so the GridView gets the images from an url? In order to help you you should provide more information about how your app is build up. Just tell. No code needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Don't use image sizes as a validation for similarity.*
Instead compare the images. The simplest way is to iterate over every 
pixel and compare the RGB value. But this will give you only a valid answer
if the images are really to 100% equal. If you like to detect similarity 
based on the image, independed of the resolution, you should search for a libary
to compare images.

**edit2:** As mentioned, it would take a while to 'compare' the images by their structure.
In this case, I would suggest to store the url, name and etag in a database
and save the images via a UUID and make a db lookup (fast) if you want to save an image.
But don't reinvent the wheel. Just use a libary that is
able to handle this kind of image storing. I recommend [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

**edit:** I can give you a sample code for pixel iteration. Feel free to enhance it:

```
public static void iterateOverImage(BufferedImage image){  
    int currentColor;
    for(int x = 0; x < widthInPx; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < heightInPx; y++){
            currentColor = image.getRGB(x, y);
            //do something with it (i.e comparison)
        }
    }
}
```

**edit3:**

```
    public int sizeInByte() {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
        o.writeObject(yourObject);
        o.flush();
        o.close();
        return b.length;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ExceptionHandler.logAndSendException(e);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And cgew85 answer!

Sorry for my english and greets, Steve.

Comment: He cannot do that having 1000 jpg files to inspect. Consider only the time it would take. And the .jpg's would have to be converted back to Bitmap's and would not be equal to the original Bitmap.

Comment: Of course he can. He want's to compare only images that should be saved. And, for clarification, tell me how image handling libaries are doing this kind of comparison if not by pixel iterations.

Comment: `He want's to compare only images that should be saved`. No. He wants to compare an unsaved Bitmap with a number of jpg files. Well you suggest that anyhow.

Comment: That's what I said. An unsaved image (the image that should be saved). But nevertheless, thanks for the hint, I edited my answer.

Comment: `Sorry for my english`. You are excused.

Comment: guys just help me with getting image size from imageview that's it

Comment: File size is the false approach.

Comment: `guys just help me with getting image size from imageview`. That is impossible. If you would save it as a bitmap you could determine filesize. But if you had more images with the same resolution all would have the same filesize. So please answer my questions. You need a different approch to obtain what you want.

Comment: Compression is indeed a problem, for any similarity validation. I would use Picasso and stop to compare any files. You said you download the images, than you've got a url, use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use length() method of File. Like:

```
long size = yourFile.length();
```

JavaDocs:

> Returns the length of the file denoted by this abstract pathname. The return value is unspecified if this pathname denotes a directory.

However I strongly recommend a hash value instead of the file size.

Comment: used this but not working: `long size = fullImageView.length();`

Comment: What kind of object is fullImageView?Because you used .getWidth() in your example :S